# RotaTiva not working in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

My application is in asp.net mvc 5 on .net framework version 4.5.2

I am using Rotavita to convert view in pdf

I tried adding Rotavita package by Giorgio Bozio from nugget

[image]

It get install and added new folder by the name RotaVita in my project with exe file

[image]

But I am not able to use it in controller as it is not available there

[image]

After some googling I found a post suggesting to use Rotavita.MVC by Dmitry Pronin . It get install without any problem and now I am able to use it in controller by including

```
using Rotativa.MVC;
```

and in action method

```
return new ViewAsPdf("Index", Model) { FileName="rpt.pdf"};
```

It does return a PDF File but it does not contain anything , a blank pdf file

[image]

I am using RotaVita in asp.net core 2.0 and its work perfectly , but not in asp.net mvc 5

How can I make it work here?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an ActionLink in the main(index) cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("Convert View To PDF", "PrintViewToPdf")
```

and in the controller

```
public ActionResult PrintViewToPdf()
{    
    var report = new ActionAsPdf("Index or Partial View Name");
    return report;    
}
```

Refer this link for extra details, as well try to use "Rotativa.MVC"
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-export-pdf-document-from-view-page/

Comment: Could you make it to work? (return new ActionAsPdf("Index", Model) you don't need to pass the Model there if you already return the model from your "Index"

Comment: Its working in new Project but not in that , I guess some other package creating problem , And I am using return new ViewAsPdf () , Sorry for the typo

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your code. You need to change it to "Rotativa", not "Rotavita".